# Generación de json con una consulta de sql server

Tags: sql, json

Estoy construyendo un json a partir de una consulta pero al final de la misma deseo incluir unos datos de control que van al final del archivo, tengo la siguiente consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito al final del corchete cuadrado es decir al final de todos los registros del JSON
enviar 2 valores adicionales de control para ese archivo, es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo incluir estos campo1 y campo2 dentro del query que genera al json?

```
select top 3 Id, Valor1, Valor2   from tabla where id>11 FOR JSON PATH, 
ROOT ('ENCABEZADO')
```

Les agradezco cualquier idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa una consulta que seleccione 3 elementos:

- Una subconsulta que devuelve el JSON de los datos de la tabla y le asignas el alias 'Encabezado'
- el valor del primer escalar con su alias
- el valor del segundo escalar con su alias.

Finalmente conviertes a JSON la consulta entera:

```
DECLARE 
@var1 varchar(100) = 'campo1',
@var2 varchar(100) = 'campo2'

SELECT 
(SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Template FOR JSON PATH) AS Encabezado,
@var1 AS "Variable1",
@var2 AS "Variable2"
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Cambia 'Template' por el nombre de tu tabla. **WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER** es para eliminar el array que envuelve el JSON, que se genera por la instrucción SELECT.

Comment: que bien, era el query que necesitaba  muchas gracias